# Related to testing my component React testing library with jest and materialUi component

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, material-ui, react-testing-library

```
import React from 'react';
import { render,fireEvent,cleanup} from '@testing-library/react';
import {SystemDecimal} from '../index'

afterEach(cleanup);
describe('Decimal',()=>{
 let metadata = {
      name: "decimal",
      title: "decimal",
      type: "DECIMAL",
      placeHolder: "enter decimal value",
      info: "enter decimal value",
      visible: false,
      numberOfDecimals:2,
      disable: false,
      required: true,
      visibleOnCsv: false
  },
  onChange=jest.fn();

  const wrapper = render( <SystemDecimal fieldmeta={metadata} 
  onChange={onChange}  />)
  const textInput = wrapper.findByTestId('decimal')
  it ('checks the input value',()=>{
      fireEvent.change(textInput,{target:{value:'test'}})
        expect(textInput.value).toBe('test')
    })
   })
```

I use material-ui textField for input text box for my decimal component. When I fire a change event, material-ui onChange function is firing, but I want to fire an onChange of my component, how do I test my component.  Here is the link: https://codesandbox.io/s/agitated-mestorf-duw72

Comment: Can you add your respective code here in your post.

Comment: this is link to my code
https://codesandbox.io/s/agitated-mestorf-duw72